# Can I display where a Python regex matches up to?

Tags: python, regex

So I've got a long input string that I extract several bits of data from using a single regex. The input is provided by the client and they often forget important parts that aren't just necessary for the regex to match (they are) but they're integral to the database this regex builds.

I'd like to be able to point out *where* in the input the match starts to fail and *why* (show them what the regex was expecting next).

Performance is an issue. The regex contains several fields so breaking this into several separate regex matches may be prohibitive.

Here's a cut down version of the real thing:

```
^(?:(?P<doors>\d) Doors).*(?P<transmission>Automatic|Manual)
```

And some sample input (and desired output):

```
"3 Doors blah blah blah Manual"  # match!
"Guadeloupe blah blah blah Sneezes"  # Reply: Missing doors
"2 Doors blah blah blah Psychic" # Reply: Missing transmission
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example that is easier to comprehend?

Comment: A match doesn't 'start to fail'. A regular expression either matches or it doesn't match.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Refer the commercial solutions like [Welcome to Regex Match Tracer 3.0](http://www.regex-match-tracer.com/) or [Regex Buddy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy.html)

Comment: @Tichodroma I'm not trying to debate the correct nomenclature of what I'm trying to achieve, I'm just trying to get something working. By all means correct me and push me in the right direction but I think it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you talking about something like this? http://pastebin.com/8qgcVA1w

Comment: @wei2912 That could work. I'm hesitant about splitting this up into *n* separate expressions because *n*=8 and the number of times this is run an hour is in the thousands. I could just run it "on fail" but this requires keeping a duplicate copy of the regex all broken up which isn't very DRY. There's also the problem of splitting the input string on partial match so the next regex can be run against it. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: @Oli if performance is an issue, I think you should write a parser instead that can report errors when an invalid part is found. This will be much faster than a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thought of writing a parser (it's been at least 10 years since my JavaCC days) makes me feel a little squiffy and I'm not sold on it being any faster than just running a bunch of compiled REGEXES... However, I think I've come up with a suitable workaround.

We use a single regex first and *if that fails*, we bust out the incremental ones. Provided the fail rate is lowish, this shoudn't be a performance issue at all.

```
REGEXES = [
    (r'(?:(?P<doors>\d) Doors)', 'doors'),
    (r'.*(?P<transmission>Automatic|Manual)', 'transmission'),
]
FAILS = [(re.compile('^' + r[0], re.IGNORECASE), r[1]) for r in REGEXES]
MATCHER = re.compile('^' + ''.join([r[0] for r in REGEXES]), re.IGNORECASE)


# ... later ...

m = MATCHER.match(input)

if not m:
    working = input
    for r in FAILS:
        s = r[0].split(input)
        if len(s) > 1:
            working = s[-1]  # we use last group in the split
            continue
        # we have a problem here!!
        # we know the group (the regex and the label we gave it)
        # we can show the user what we're trying to match and against what
        return blah

# otherwise we can start working with m's groups.
```

Comment: A parser is faster because a regex and its specific parts (since the regex is being split) needs to be compiled, whereas a parser is already compiled and can point out an error whenever it reaches an invalid point.

Comment: This is useful if you can separately define the conditions (similar to how password validation is done), so we can test each condition separately and returns meaningful feedback. However, if the conditions cannot be separate, it is ill-defined to tell why a regex fails, since there are many points where it stops and have to backtrack.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is too broad to be handled by Python Regex Engine. You need a finite automata engine (more specific NFA), write your own parser and feed the string and see where it fails and why.

Alternatively, you can use [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), create a Grammar (loads of example you will find in the [PyParsing Wiki](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples)) something like http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/dfmparse.py
. In case you are new to PyParsing, there would be a steep learning curve, but once you grasp the concept, implementing what you intend would be a cake walk.

Comment: I'm not sold no the premise that a Parser would be quicker than chunking up the regex for such a simple problem scope. I've added an example that shows how chunking could work.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing